# Capybara does not waiting for ajax to finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to test a signup flow using rspec and cpaybara within a feature spec. The signup happens via ajax and capybara doesn't wait for the request to complete. I am using the capybara matchers as specified in the documentation. If I add a sleep statement the test succeeds

```
let(:user) { create(:user, email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password') }

scenario 'visitor can sign up with valid email address and password', js: true do
   sign_up_with('Name', 'test@example.com', 'password')
   expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t( 'devise.registrations.signed_up'))
end
```

Helper Method to handle signup:

```
def sign_up_with(name, email, password)
  visit root_path
  find(:xpath,"//a[text()='Join']").click

  within("#sign_up_choices") do
    click_on "Sign up with Email"
  end

  within("#sign_up") do
    fill_in 'user[name]', with: name
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: email
    fill_in 'user[password]', with: password
    click_button 'Sign up'
  end
end
```

When the user clicks on signup the form gets submitted via ajax.

Error I am getting occasionally:

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError:
       stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
         (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935    (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting? and where does adding a sleep make it work?

Comment: You should do some check if any ajax request if active. Hope its help with this article https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: @DharmaSaputra There are very few cases where any type of 'wait-for-ajax'  is necessary - and when it is it often means a bad UI design (as mentioned in the article you linked).  The code in this question is correct and should be waiting just fine, unless `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` is set too short.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for your reply. I also read that a manual wait for ajax should not be necessary if the capybara matchers are being used correctly. If I add a sleep statement at the end of the sign_up_with method the test succeeds. I am getting different errors:

Comment: I added the error on top in my question.

Comment: @JohannesEngl  What do you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time set to?  Try making it longer, or passing a longer time to the expect - `expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t( 'devise.registrations.signed_up'), wait: 10)` - thats assuming you're getting the error on the expectation

Comment: you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20455051/1380867

Comment: @ThomasWalpole increasing the wait time on the expect statement solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help!